# Yocto rtsp stream

Tags: linux, video-streaming, gstreamer, rtsp, yocto

I'm fairly new to Linux, but have to create a custom Yocto OS for raspberry pi 3 that would be able to stream a web cam's video using RTSP. I've managed to launch the web cam's video stream using UDP and view it on other devices on the same network, but I can't seem to be able to stream using RTSP.

I'm using this to start the stream on the raspberry:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=(IP of the device I'm streaming to) port=5000
```

This to view the stream on the external device:

```
   gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=JPEG,payload=26 ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! autovideosink
```

And this in the stream.sdp file to view the stream using VLC:

```
v=0
m=video 5000 RTP/AVP 26
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
a=rtpmap:26 JPEG/90000
```

I've tried following multiple tutorials, but they're either outdated or I assume my Linux knowledge is lacking in order to execute all the steps correctly and I can't download any files since there are no repositories enabled and I need everything to be included in the image anyways. For example, I found this tutorial https://community.nxp.com/thread/380070, but since I've been doing all the customization using Toaster, I'm unsure which  steps I need to do manually and which will be done by Toaster. Any instructions regarding this would be greatly appreciated!

I'm using the poky distro and gstreamer1.0 (with plugins and rtsp-server) and Toaster to build/customize the images. My custom image is based on core-image-sato-dev, since I noticed it has a GUI for mobile devices and hoped it would support commands like git/gcc/etc. These are the layers I'm currently using:

```
openembedded-core
meta-poky
meta-yocto-bsp
meta-oe
meta-raspberrypi
toaster-custom-images
```

Comment: Take a look at the rtsp-server of gstreamer (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/#gstreamer-rtsp-server). This will add the extra on top of RTP to stream with RTSP.